# How do I walk a bidirectional iterator backwards in clean code?

Tags: c++, c++11, containers

Suppose I have an std::map and want to do something to the item with key X and every item with a higher key (remember, this is an ordered map). The code is obvious and clear:

```
auto iter = mymap.find(X);
while (iter != mymap.end()) {
    process(*iter);
    iter++;
}
```

or, possibly better, `std::for_each(mymap.find(X), mymap.end(), process)`.

But if my task is to perform processing on the item with key X and every item with a *lower* key, in that order, I can't find a clean coding pattern that expresses intent.

```
auto iter mymap.find(x);
if (iter != mymap.end()) {
    iter++;                           // Go forward...
    while (iter != mymap.begin()) {
        iter--;                       // ... so we can go backwards
        process(*iter);
    }
}
```

If I didn't want to do them in reverse order, it would be easy enough to increment the iterator returned by std::map::find() and then use std::for_each(mymap.begin(), incremented_iter, process).

Bidirectional iterators aren't reverse iterators, so I can't use `mymap.rend()` as the "off the beginning" to compare against in a while() loop.

Is there a clean way to do this in C++11 (or in +14 or +17, so I'll have something to look forward to)?

Comment: `reverse_iterator`

Answer (score 2):

You want to process every item with key X *or lower*, and to do the processing starting at the element with key X and then go backwards. What you could do is use `reverse_iterator` on the first element *past* key X and create a reverse iterator, which points to the element *just before* the one you gave it. Then you can iterate until the "reverse end":

```
auto pastX = mymap.upper_bound(X); // First element with key > X
// make_reverse_iterator returns iter that dereferences to the previous element
for (auto iter = std::make_reverse_iterator(pastX); iter != mymap.rend(); ++iter)
    // Use *iter
```

For better readability, I usually keep some helper functions to create an "iterable object" (one which can be called with `.begin()` and `.end()`) from a pair of iterators, so I would actually write:

```
auto pastX = mymap.upper_bound(X);
// "IteRange" would return a "range-for-iterable" object from two iterators
for (auto&& elem : IteRange(std::make_reverse_iterator(pastX), mymap.rend()))
    // Use elem
```

Comment: The key fact that I'd missed was converting the bidirectional iterator returned from std::map::find() to a reverse iterator. I can't be quite as concise as your code here; my context requires me to throw if X isn't actually in the map. That's only one extra check, though, so it's still pretty clean.

I don't suppose you've made that helper function available via gist or GitHub or blog posting...

Comment: @jdzions Maybe [like this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dd626b0dccfd70eb134bde5738bf79fa)? Note that this only has the very basic requirement, which is having a begin and end method. In C++17 you would also have a size method, I think.